# How to assign a new value to a pytorch Variable without breaking backpropagation?

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch variable that is used as a trainable input for a model. At some point I need to manually reassign all values in this variable.

How can I do that without breaking the connections with the loss function?

Suppose the current values are `[1.2, 3.2, 43.2]` and I simply want them to become `[1,2,3]`.

---

#### Edit

At the time I asked this question, I hadn't realized that PyTorch doesn't have a static graph as Tensorflow or Keras do.

In PyTorch, the training loop is made manually and you need to call everything in each training step. (There isn't the notion of placeholder + static graph for later feeding data).

Consequently, we can't "break the graph", since we will use the new variable to perform all the further computations again. I was worried about a problem that happens in Keras, not in PyTorch.

Comment: What do you mean "without breaking connections"? In general, inputs to the network have `requires_grad=False` anyway and are thus not backpropagated to.

Comment: This one is `require_grad=True` (intentionally). Suppose I want to change the weights of a layer.

Comment: So is it _input_ or layer weights? Will just assigning a different tensor in place of the old one work? The old one will be retained as long as it's necessary for computation graph (backprop)

Comment: Assigning a different tensor is not an option (Unless I don't understand what this means). I want to reassign the values of the var keeping it in the same graph.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `data` attribute of tensors to modify the values, since modifications on `data` do not affect the graph. 
So the graph will still be intact and modifications of the `data` attribute itself have *no* influence on the graph. (Operations and changes on `data` are not tracked by autograd and thus not present in the graph)

Since you haven't given an example, this example is based on your comment statement:
 *'Suppose I want to change the weights of a layer.'* 

I used normal tensors here, but this works the same for `weight.data` and `bias.data` attributes of a layers.

Here is a short example:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F



# Test 1, random vector with CE
w1 = torch.rand(1, 3, requires_grad=True)
loss = F.cross_entropy(w1, torch.tensor([1]))
loss.backward()
print('w1.data', w1)
print('w1.grad', w1.grad)
print()

# Test 2, replacing values of w2 with w1, before CE
# to make sure that everything is exactly like in Test 1 after replacing the values
w2 = torch.zeros(1, 3, requires_grad=True)
w2.data = w1.data
loss = F.cross_entropy(w2, torch.tensor([1]))
loss.backward()
print('w2.data', w2)
print('w2.grad', w2.grad)
print()

# Test 3, replace data after computation
w3 = torch.rand(1, 3, requires_grad=True)
loss = F.cross_entropy(w3, torch.tensor([1]))
# setting values
# the graph of the previous computation is still intact as you can in the below print-outs
w3.data = w1.data
loss.backward()

# data were replaced with values from w1
print('w3.data', w3)
# gradient still shows results from computation with w3
print('w3.grad', w3.grad)
```

Output:

```
w1.data tensor([[ 0.9367,  0.6669,  0.3106]])
w1.grad tensor([[ 0.4351, -0.6678,  0.2326]])

w2.data tensor([[ 0.9367,  0.6669,  0.3106]])
w2.grad tensor([[ 0.4351, -0.6678,  0.2326]])

w3.data tensor([[ 0.9367,  0.6669,  0.3106]])
w3.grad tensor([[ 0.3179, -0.7114,  0.3935]])
```

The most interesting part here is `w3`. At the time `backward` is called the values are replaced by values of `w1`. 
But the gradients are calculated based on the CE-function with values of original `w3`. The replaced values have no effect on the graph.
So the graph connection is *not* broken, replacing had *no* influence on graph. I hope this is what you were looking for!

Comment: Not really... this is "disconnected" from the graph, it's not useful as the new data will not be trained. I want to change data "in the graph" and keep everything trainable as before with new values. Example: why would I change the weights of a layer if the weights will not participate in the graph? The only reason to change the weights is that they take the place of the old weights.

Comment: @DanielMöller Thanks for your feedback! How do you conclude that the new data will not be trained? Only the process of replacing the weights is not recorded in the graph, nothing there is disconnected. But the replaced weights should be treated then as if they were there from the beginning for future calculations. But I guess I did not really understand what you are looking for. Can you add a small example with expected outcome to your question?

Comment: You clearly changed w3's data and it didn't take effect in the graph by looking at its gradients.

Comment: So what is your problem then? I though this what you wanted to archive. As I understand your question, what you want to do is: *Replacing values of a tensor where `requires_grad` is active, while keeping the previous graph, meaning no reset or interference with the previously computed graph through replacing values.* As said above it would be great if you could add an example or edit your question with some more details about what you *exactly* want to do.

Comment: What I want is your example, where w3 computes the gradients according to its actual data.

Comment: Well... I must sort of rebuild the graph if I want the new data to take effect. I assume this is the only way pytorch works?

Comment: Yes, there isn't really a way of directly interacting with the graph itself.