# How does one implement a meta-trainable step size in Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to implement a (meta) trainable step size. I tried it with this post:

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-does-one-have-the-parameters-of-a-model-not-be-leafs/70076/17

and with the higher library (https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher) with no luck...

I tried:

```
eta = torch.tensor([0.5], requires_grad=True).view(1)
inner_opt = torch.optim.Adam(child_model.parameters(), lr=eta)
#meta_params = itertools.chain(child_model.parameters(),eta.parameters())
meta_params = itertools.chain(child_model.parameters())
meta_opt = torch.optim.Adam(meta_params, lr=1e-3)
# do meta-training/outer training minimize outerloop: min_{theta} sum_t L^val( theta^{T} - eta* Grad L^train(theta^{T}) ) 
nb_outer_steps = 10 # note, in this case it's the same as number of meta-train steps (but it's could not be the same depending how you loop through the val set)
for outer_i, (outer_inputs, outer_targets) in enumerate(testloader, 0):
    meta_opt.zero_grad()
    if outer_i >= nb_outer_steps:
        break
    # do inner-training/MAML; minimize innerloop: theta^{T} - eta* Grad L^train(theta^{T}) ~ argmin L^train(theta)
    nb_inner_steps = 3
    with higher.innerloop_ctx(child_model, inner_opt) as (fmodel, diffopt):
```

with error:

```
Exception has occurred: RuntimeError
Only Tensors created explicitly by the user (graph leaves) support the deepcopy protocol at the moment
```

which wouldn't work anyway cuz eta might become negative suddenly so I really want to cap it with a sigmoid function but had to try something...

---

It thinks my step size NN is not in the graph but it is because of this line of code:

```
            p_new = p + lr*g
            group['params'][p_idx] = p_new
```

but somehow that is not enough to have gradients...

Full script self contained script:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.optim.optimizer import Optimizer

import higher
from higher.optim import DifferentiableOptimizer
from higher.optim import DifferentiableSGD

import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

from torchviz import make_dot

import copy

import itertools

from collections import OrderedDict

#mini class to add a flatten layer to the ordered dictionary
class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        '''
        Note that input.size(0) is usually the batch size.
        So what it does is that given any input with input.size(0) # of batches,
        will flatten to be 1 * nb_elements.
        '''
        batch_size = input.size(0)
        out = input.view(batch_size,-1)
        return out # (batch_size, *size)

def get_cifar10():
    transform = transforms.Compose(
        [transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True,
                                            download=True, transform=transform)
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                            shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=False,
                                        download=True, transform=transform)
    testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                            shuffle=False, num_workers=2)
    return trainloader, testloader

class MySGD(Optimizer):

    def __init__(self, params, eta, prev_lr):
        defaults = {'eta':eta, 'prev_lr':prev_lr}
        super().__init__(params, defaults)

class TrainableSGD(DifferentiableOptimizer):

    def _update(self, grouped_grads, **kwargs):
        prev_lr = self.param_groups[0]['prev_lr']
        eta = self.param_groups[0]['eta']
        # start differentiable & trainable update
        zipped = zip(self.param_groups, grouped_grads)
        lr = 0.1*eta(prev_lr).view(1)
        for group_idx, (group, grads) in enumerate(zipped):
            for p_idx, (p, g) in enumerate(zip(group['params'], grads)):
                if g is None:
                    continue
                #group['params'][p_idx] = _add(p, -group['lr'], g)
                p_new = p + lr*g
                group['params'][p_idx] = p_new
        # fake returns
        self.param_groups[0]['prev_lr'] = lr

higher.register_optim(MySGD, TrainableSGD)

def main():
    # get dataloaders
    trainloader, testloader = get_cifar10()
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    child_model = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
            ('conv1', nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3,out_channels=2,kernel_size=5)),
            ('relu1', nn.ReLU()),
            ('Flatten', Flatten()),
            ('fc', nn.Linear(in_features=28*28*2,out_features=10) )
        ]))

    hidden = torch.randn(size=(1,1),requires_grad=True)
    print(f'-> hidden = {hidden}')
    eta = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
        ('fc', nn.Linear(1,1)),
        ('sigmoid', nn.Sigmoid())
    ]))
    inner_opt = MySGD(child_model.parameters(), eta=eta, prev_lr=hidden)
    meta_params = itertools.chain(child_model.parameters(),eta.parameters())
    #meta_params = itertools.chain(eta.parameters(),[hidden])
    meta_opt = torch.optim.Adam(meta_params, lr=1e-3)
    # do meta-training/outer training minimize outerloop: min_{theta} sum_t L^val( theta^{T} - eta* Grad L^train(theta^{T}) ) 
    print()
    nb_outer_steps = 1 # note, in this case it's the same as number of meta-train steps (but it's could not be the same depending how you loop through the val set)
    for outer_i, (outer_inputs, outer_targets) in enumerate(testloader, 0):
        meta_opt.zero_grad()
        if outer_i >= nb_outer_steps:
            break
        # do inner-training/MAML; minimize innerloop: theta^{T} - eta * Grad L^train(theta^{T}) ~ argmin L^train(theta)
        nb_inner_steps = 3
        #with higher.innerloop_ctx(child_model, inner_opt, copy_initial_weights=False) as (fmodel, diffopt):
        with higher.innerloop_ctx(child_model, inner_opt) as (fmodel, diffopt):
            for inner_i, (inner_inputs, inner_targets) in enumerate(trainloader, 0):
                if inner_i >= nb_inner_steps:
                    break
                logits = fmodel(inner_inputs)
                inner_loss = criterion(logits, inner_targets)
                print(f'--> inner_i = {inner_i}')
                print(f'inner_loss^<{inner_i}>: {inner_loss}')
                print(f'lr^<{inner_i-1}> = {diffopt.param_groups[0]["prev_lr"]}') 
                diffopt.step(inner_loss) # changes params P[t+1] using P[t] and loss[t] in a differentiable manner
                print(f'lr^<{inner_i}> = {diffopt.param_groups[0]["prev_lr"]}')
                print()
            # compute the meta-loss L^val( theta^{T} - eta* Grad L^train(theta^{T}) ) 
            outer_outputs = fmodel(outer_inputs)
            meta_loss = criterion(outer_outputs, outer_targets) # L^val
            make_dot(meta_loss).render('meta_loss',format='png')
            meta_loss.backward()
            #grad_of_grads = torch.autograd.grad(outputs=meta_loss, inputs=eta.parameters()) # dmeta_loss/dw0
            print(f'----> outer_i = {outer_i}')
            print(f'-> outer_loss/meta_loss^<{outer_i}>: {meta_loss}')
            print(f'child_model.fc.weight.grad = {child_model.fc.weight.grad}')
            print(f'hidden.grad = {hidden.grad}')
            print(f'eta.fc.weight = {eta.fc.weight.grad}')
            meta_opt.step() # meta-optimizer step: more or less theta^<t> := theta^<t> - meta_eta * Grad L^val( theta^{T} - eta* Grad L^train(theta^{T}) )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    print('---> Done\a')
```

notice the None's:

Files already downloaded and verifiedFiles already downloaded and verified
-> hidden = tensor([[0.8459]], requires_grad=True)

--> inner_i = 0
inner_loss^<0>: 2.2696359157562256
lr^<-1> = tensor([[0.8459]], requires_grad=True)
lr^<0> = tensor([0.0567], grad_fn=)

--> inner_i = 1
inner_loss^<1>: 2.0114920139312744
lr^<0> = tensor([0.0567], grad_fn=)
lr^<1> = tensor([0.0720], grad_fn=)

--> inner_i = 2
inner_loss^<2>: 2.3866422176361084
lr^<1> = tensor([0.0720], grad_fn=)
lr^<2> = tensor([0.0717], grad_fn=)

----> outer_i = 0
-> outer_loss/meta_loss^<0>: 4.021303176879883
child_model.fc.weight.grad = None
hidden.grad = None
eta.fc.weight = None
---> Done

---

related:

- pytorch forum: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/implement-a-meta-trainable-step-size/70396
- gitissue: https://github.com/facebookresearch/higher/issues/32
- related SO Q: [How does one have parameters in a pytorch model not be leafs and be in the computation graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60271131/how-does-one-have-parameters-in-a-pytorch-model-not-be-leafs-and-be-in-the-compu)