# Update custom parameter in forward pass pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to create a custom vector that can be later optimized in Pytorch. To do so, I created the following class:

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class customVector(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, S):
        super().__init__()

        self.vector = nn.Parameter(torch.sqrt(torch.ones((1,S))/S))

    def forward(self, x):
        #Normalise to unit norm 
        self.vector = self.vector / torch.sqrt(self.vector @ self.vector.T)

        y = x * self.vector 

        return y
```

As you can see, I need that the vector has unit norm every time it's applied. However, the operation `self.vector / torch.sqrt(self.vector @ self.vector.T)` returns a tensor, and when assigned again to `self.vector`, which is a nn.Parameter, I get the error: `TypeError: cannot assign 'torch.FloatTensor' as parameter 'vector' (torch.nn.Parameter or None expected)`.

I wonder if there's a way to constraint the vector to have unit norm every time it's applied. I thought about doing `self.vector = nn.Parameter(self.vector / torch.sqrt(self.vector @ self.vector.T))`, but I'm afraid if that would change the parameters of the network and then not optimize the vector in each iteration of the backprop.

Comment: Does this help https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-do-weight-normalization-in-last-classification-layer/35193/2 ?

Comment: I get the error: `'Parameter' object has no attribute 'weight'`

Answer (score 0):

Just convert it before assign:

```
self.vector = nn.Parameter(self.vector / torch.sqrt(self.vector @ self.vector.T))
```

you can also try to use `.data` if it does not behave as expected:

```
self.vector = (self.vector / torch.sqrt(self.vector @ self.vector.T)).data
```

some more information on that:
[How to assign a new value to a pytorch Variable without breaking backpropagation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819383/how-to-assign-a-new-value-to-a-pytorch-variable-without-breaking-backpropagation)

Comment: A simple comment suggesting his code will work, which is the same as your answer would probably do..

Comment: But does that change the parameters of the network? When doing loss.backward() later it still optimizes the same vector?