# How to replace the value of multiple cells in multiple rows in a Pytorch tensor?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a tensor

```
import torch
torch.zeros((5,10))

>>> tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

How can I replace the values of X random cells in each row with random inputs (`torch.rand()`)?

That is, if `X = 2`, in each row, 2 random cells should be replaced with `torch.rand()`.
Since I need it to not break backpropagation I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819383/how-to-assign-a-new-value-to-a-pytorch-variable-without-breaking-backpropagation) that replacing the `.data` attribute of the cells should work.

The only familiar thing to me is using a `for` loop but it's not efficient for a large tensor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`tensor.scatter_()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_).

```
x = torch.zeros(3,4)
n_replace = 3 # number of cells to be replaced with random number
src = torch.randn(x.size())
index = torch.stack([torch.randperm(x.size()[1]) for _ in range(x.size()[0])])[:,:n_replace]

x.scatter_(1, index, src)
Out[22]: 
tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.5769,  0.7432, -0.1776],
        [-2.1673, -1.0802,  0.0000,  0.6241],
        [-0.6421,  0.1315,  0.0000, -2.7224]])
```

To avoid repetition,

```
perm = torch.randperm(tensor.size(0))
idx = perm[:k]
samples = tensor[idx]
```

Comment: Looks good. A few questions. Since I'm interested in keeping this backprop-feasible, will this work? `x.data.scatter_(1, index, src)`? Also, this seems to choose cells that might be the same. I ran `index = torch.randint(0, x.size()[1], (x.size()[0],4))` and got `index tensor([[1, 2, 0, 3],
        [2, 0, 1, 2],
        [3, 3, 0, 0]])`. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: The gradient should remain. I update the answer for sampling without replacement.